# how to process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(str1,str2,str3.....)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find more than one  MainWindowTitle to a process

For example:-  I have a string in My.resource like this: google:yahoo:msn:ebay....etc and I have this code to look if one of the strings in my resource string exists to show a message box

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim LOKUP As New Process
    For Each LOKUP In Process.GetProcesses
        If LOKUP.MainWindowTitle.Contains(Split(My.Resources.String2, ":").ToString) Then
            MsgBox("Allowed - Site - Web")
        Else
            MsgBox("This Site Is Forbidden Sorry")
            'close site
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

the problem this code didn't work because the function Contains have only one string.

Comment: this isn't a very sufficient way to lookup website names going off their title's... especially if you are going to try and stop someone from navigating to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nest an additional For Each and then use a Boolean to display the message box.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim LOKUP As New Process
    Dim SiteFlag As Boolean = False
    For Each LOKUP In Process.GetProcesses
        For Each site As String in My.Resources.String2.Split(":")
            If LOKUP.MainWindowTitle.Contains(site) Then
                SiteFlag = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If SiteFlag Then
        MsgBox("Allowed - Site - Web")
    Else
        MsgBox("This Site Is Forbidden Sorry")
        'close site
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for fast replay,but i get an error under split (syntax error) I am using netframework 2

Comment: thank you . I tried your code and it seems not working as expected the message box MsgBox("Allowed - Site - Web") is displayed even if the site is not allowed or no site has been visited??

Comment: Does `My.Resources.String2` contain a list of allowed sites or not allowed sites?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `Process.GetProcesses` is pulling your desired list of processes?  Your simplified example looks like your comparing against every process currently running on the PC, not just web browsers.

Comment: I haven't understood what you mean,but I think I am comparing my resource string to any string in any process and because my resource strings are for sites only I think it will appear in web browsers only

Comment: Please post your entire `My.Resources.String2`

Comment: Yahoo:Recherche Google:MSN:Welcome to Facebook:Gmail:Blogger:Wikipedia

Comment: When you step through the code, in debug, what is the match that is triggering the "Allowed" message?